# Activity doesn't start on phone booting, Android BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to start an activity when mobile will boot. Its fine when I start the app from my mobile but the activity doesn't start when I am restarting my mobile. There is no error in the LogCat.
I am posting my full code so that you guys can understand.

Here is my

- main activity

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
      startActivity(browserIntent);
  }
  ```

  }

here is my another class

- BootReciever

  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;

  public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

  ```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub


      new Thread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(5000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              }

              Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
              myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              context.startActivity(myIntent);
          }
      }).start();

  }
  ```

  }
- mainfest XML

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
  </uses-permission>

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="11"
      android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <receiver
          android:name="com.android.bitter.BootReciever"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
  </application>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.android.bitter.BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```